# Erro ao tentar fazer atualização pelo Maven

Tags: java, maven

Estou com erro após configuração no arquivo `pom.xml` no artefato `<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>`.

Este é o erro ao tentar fazer atualização pelo Maven:

```
Could not update project comecando-primeface configuration
Version 1.8 of project facet java does not exist.
```

Comment: Está ok pela linha de comando? Isto é em alguma `IDE`, tipo eclipse? Se for, veja se há um `JDK` que seja da versão 8 configurado no `IDE`.

Comment: @Robson, tente postar seu pom.xml todo.
De uma olhada nessa resposta, veja se isso te atende:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715260/java-compiler-level-does-not-match-the-version-of-the-installed-java-project-fac

Se funcionar eu bolo uma resposta oficial para você